# WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 - Clustered & Distributed - How to Publish an API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

According to the [installation guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Deploying+WSO2+API-M+in+a+Distributed+Setup), when configuring the publisher with the gateway; on the publisher node you need to point the "APIGateway.Environments.Environment.ServerURL" to any one of the gateway worker nodes admin service endpoint in order for the gateway worker node to create the synapse file there.

When this happens in my deployment the following error is thrown:

```
[2019-08-11 08:10:38,878]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@wso2.com@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-08-11 08:10:38,878+0000]
[2019-08-11 08:10:38,892] ERROR - Class Invoking admin services on worker node is forbidden...
```

Should the documentation be changed so that the ServerURL should point to the publisher? If so, how can multi-gateway deployments be achieved?

Deployment;

- fully distributed
- no gateway manager node, no hazelcast

Comment: How did u start the gateway node? When publishing you should point the gateway node from publishing?

Comment: Did u specify as follows?
-Dprofile=gateway-worker -DworkerNode=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you used `-DworkerNode` parameter to start the gateway nodes, just don't.

**Long answer:**

If you have only a single gateway environment, you can use the publisher service URL itself as you have guessed correctly.

In the case of multiple gateway environments, you can use each gateway URL here. But you should not use `-DworkerNode` parameter when you start the gateway nodes. Simply use the profile only like this[1].

```
./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=gateway-worker
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Product+Profiles

Comment: Wonderful, that worked. I had left that in my puppet template from the previous version (2.1.0)